# R: Output columns as text

Tags: r, text, output

Background: I have survey results in an SPSS .sav file.  Some of the survey questions were open, where respondents could type their own responses.  In SPSS, I can just select one or more columns, and the responses will be output as a text file, with the responses grouped by each question (column contents), and each response separated by a blank line.  This text file can then be used for thematic analysis by assigning code to phrases or sentences in the text.

I can't seem to find an easy way of doing the same thing in R.  All the usual export formats output as a table.  Selecting the columns in RStudio gives text output where each the responses are grouped by respondent rather than by column.

Toy example:

```
library(labelled)
library(tidyverse)

comments<-tibble(
  shakey=as.character(c("To be or not to be", "", "Alas poor Yorick", "", "Is this a dagger that I see before me?", "A rose by any other name")), 
  versey=as.character(c("", "The boy stood on the burning deck", "", "Oft in the stilly night", "", "Lars Porsena of Clusium, by the nine gods he swore"))
  )

var_label(comments$shakey)<-"Can you quote some Shakespeare?"
var_label(comments$versey)<-"Can you quote some poetry?"
```

The output I want from this is:

```
*Can you quote some Shakespeare?*

To be or not to be

Alas poor Yorick

Is this a dagger that I see before me?

A rose by any other name

*Can you quote some poetry?*

The boy stood on the burning deck

Oft in the stilly night

Lars Porsena of Clusium, by the nine gods he swore
```

with the column label as the heading and each column's non-blank responses listed one after the other, separated by a blank line.

The closest I've come so far is:

```
comlong<-pivot_longer(comments, everything(),
                     names_to="question",
                     values_to="response") %>%
  arrange(question) %>% 
  filter(response!="")
```

but while that gets all the responses in one column, it needs a bit of editing to get it into the desired format above, which is non-trivial on more extensive data.

Final result:

Akrun's additional `summarise` line is, I think, the most elegant.  Tweaking that gives output very similar to SPSS:

```
comments %>%
  summarise(across(everything(), ~ c(paste0(sprintf('**%s**', cur_column()), "\n\n", sprintf('*%s*', var_label(.))), .))) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = everything(), 
               names_to = 'question', 
               values_to = 'response') %>% 
  arrange(question) %>% 
  filter(response != '') %>% 
  select(response) %>% 
  write.table("comments.md",quote=FALSE, eol="\n\n", row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE)
```

This inserts the column name as well as the label (because I found that sometimes the labels are not sufficiently descriptive), and outputs it as a markdown file, which can be ingested for thematic coding in (eg) [Qualcoder](https://github.com/ccbogel/QualCoder).  Running:

```
pandoc comments.md -o comments.odt
```

will also produce word-processor output if you need it.

Comment: Just trying to understand why you want this bad format, i.e. why exactly do you need it in this format for thematic analysis? If you juts want the text to be shown below each other, the pivot_longer seems to be a good approach, you could then replace your column names by the column label in the "question" column and do your coding of responses in a new column.

Comment: This is standard input for qualitative analysis tools like Qualcoder, Nvivo, Atlas.TI, etc, where you want to focus on what everyone said about one topic, rather than on what each person said about all topics.  Coding (marking the theme) in a new column would not work, because frequently one comment will relate to multiple themes, and you want to keep them separate for later analysis.

Comment: This is true for "real" qualitative analysis, e.g. when you have transcripts from focus groups or in-dpeth interviews that you want to code in e.g. MaxQDA or Qualcoder etc. sing these tools, you usually want to also take into consideration the space/length, position, overlap of certain topics (e.g. if person A and person B are mentioned in the same sentence). Analysing open text responses from surveys usually means you only want to code the occurence of topics regardless of other qualitative features. Hence, you'll probably have a "codebook" with your topics, each topic has a numeric code...

Comment: ...and then you just want to cde if topic A, and/or topic B, C, D etc. occur. In the simplest form, this just requires as many columns to the right of your text column where you assign these codes. Typically, you'd then convert this into a dichotomous format where you have as many coded columns as you have topics and you assign a 1 if the respective topic occurs or the 0 if not (this then allows for multiple coding). This can then be easily analyzed. That's why I was asking which exact format you need. You can do this in R or Excel or in tools like Caplena (not free) or other such tools.

Comment: But developing the codebook may be an exploratory process.  And the "code columns" may be organised haphazardly.  And it's easier to select a stretch of text in a text file than scroll across x columns to get to the right one.  And seeing context for a code should ideally allow you to see all comments, and that's difficult in a spreadsheet format.  And sometimes getting R to do the "obvious" thing is not obvious.  So yes, I agree you could use the tools you mention, but it's probably faster to use one designed for that task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `summarise` with `across` first to extract the `var_label` and append by concatenating, then use `pivot_longer`

```
library(labelled)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
comments %>% 
    summarise(across(everything(), ~ c(var_label(.), .))) %>% 
    pivot_longer(cols = everything(), names_to = 'question', 
        values_to = 'response') %>% 
    arrange(question) %>% 
    filter(response != '')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 9 x 2
  question response                                          
  <chr>    <chr>                                             
1 shakey   Can you quote some Shakespeare?                   
2 shakey   To be or not to be                                
3 shakey   Alas poor Yorick                                  
4 shakey   Is this a dagger that I see before me?            
5 shakey   A rose by any other name                          
6 versey   Can you quote some poetry?                        
7 versey   The boy stood on the burning deck                 
8 versey   Oft in the stilly night                           
9 versey   Lars Porsena of Clusium, by the nine gods he swore
```

---

or if we are first reshapeing first, there is an option as well i.e. do a group by 'question' and subset the first value of 'question' to extract the `var_label` from the original data and concatenate

```
pivot_longer(comments, everything(),
                     names_to="question",
                     values_to="response") %>%
  arrange(question) %>% 
  filter(response!="") %>% 
  group_by(question) %>% 
  summarise(response = c(var_label(comments[[first(question)]]), 
     response), .groups = 'drop')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 9 x 2
  question response                                          
  <chr>    <chr>                                             
1 shakey   Can you quote some Shakespeare?                   
2 shakey   To be or not to be                                
3 shakey   Alas poor Yorick                                  
4 shakey   Is this a dagger that I see before me?            
5 shakey   A rose by any other name                          
6 versey   Can you quote some poetry?                        
7 versey   The boy stood on the burning deck                 
8 versey   Oft in the stilly night                           
9 versey   Lars Porsena of Clusium, by the nine gods he swore
```

Comment: It seems that you are quite alone here. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an output with `lapply` -

```
lapply(comments, function(x) {
  y <- x[x != '']
  values <- paste0(sprintf('*%s*', attr(x, 'label')), "\n\n", 
            paste0(y, collapse = '\n\n'))
  cat(paste0(values, '\n\n'), file = 'output.txt', append = TRUE)
})
```

[image]